# Change URL Path for View Profile Page

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am building a PHP based application which has users. Currently I have a view profile directory which has an index.php.

When a user clicks on another user's picture, I redirect them to view-profile/?u="username"

Due to this I do a get of u and show profile accordingly.

Is there a way to change the URL path to something like root/view-profile/username or better can i make it something like root/username

Is this possible through htaccess? If so, can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Your Google search term should be "mod rewrite"

Answer (score 0):

> `Is there a way to change the URL path to something like root/view-profile/username or better can i make it something like root/username`

No better keep it like `/profile/username` instead of `/username` otherwise every not found page will be treated like user profile page.

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$ /view-profile/?u=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)